# Does adding a directory as a resource in Maven include all subdirectories?

Tags: java, xml, maven

With Maven, when you add a directory as a resource (in the POM - therefore adding it to the projects classpath), are all sub-directories automatically added too?

Example:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>/project-directory/folder-in-project/resources/</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

If the directory *resources* has an XML file called A.xml in it, **and** a folder (called moreResources), which contains files B.xml and C.xml, will all the XML files be accessible to my project?

Comment: You should never have an absolute path in your resources definition...only relative path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `<directory>` specifies a root resource directory, and all the subdirectories are included.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Resource example:

```
src/main/resources/config/app.properties
```

Get File Config exmaple

```
class App{
     //Content...
     InputStream appInput = App.class.getResourceAsStream("/config/app.properties")
}
```